# Flex/Flash professional Components - What's the equivalent of companies like Telerik?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, components, flex4, flash-builder

In the .NET world order, companies like Telerik provide awesome sets of components for web/windows/silverlight.

Who are the equivalents in the Flex/Flash universe?

I see lots of sites filled with little 10/20 dollar menu components or uploaders, but I'm really looking to find something a step above that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of cools stuff here:

http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/

The tour de flex also has some eliteness to it, but some of the stuff you have to pay for:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/